# do I need to check if activity still alive when using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I remember back in days that I need to call `isFinishing()` to check if activity is still alive to avoid updating the views that no longer exist or it will throw `NullPointerException`, but I don't see this being mentioned in any retrofit's tutorial. I also ran a test and didn't see any crash. Is this already handled by retrofit? If yes, does retrofit only take care of activity or fragment as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle it. If you are using retrofit directly inside activity, you will not get NullPointerException. But even after the activity is finished, the network will still be used, the callback will be still called and the resources taken up by the activity will still be in the memory till the callback finishes.

If you are using retrofit inside fragments, you are more likely to get NullPointerException on the callback.

The best way would be to get the reference of `Call` object(s) and use `call.cancel()` inside the `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: its weird that I remember I had to check if activity still exists, but now doesn't throw any exception